# Auto-copying a value to another part of spreadsheet or new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to auto-paste any false matches to another section. Does this function exist in excel?

I have used Sort which gives the same information. Just wanted to know if the previously mentioned function exists.

Comment: `FILTER` maybe?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "false match" - you've not given us anything to go on (e.g. sample data, expected results)
Sounds like something you could easily achieve using Power Query though

Comment: I am looking to duplicate records that contain "No Match" in one of the record cells.

Comment: yeah totally - what is a false match (surely this means 'no match found' ? (that would be "error match" - not sure... so you're looking for auto-paste on cells within a column that couldn't be matched (if so, surely it makes sense to ask in words that are unambiguous like this?)

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(A2:D12,--NOT(ISNUMBER(D2#)))
```

[image: Filter function]

Per @BigBen (first comment / suggestion to OP Q).

*Assumes "False Match" means "no match" (as opposed to some analogue of "False positive" {e.g. incorrectly matched - for which there is no tractable way to generalise a method/function applicable to all possible variations that give rise to such an outcome})..

---

The only other 'automatic' (albeit completely 'manual' in relation to above function) "paste-only" method would be to filter on errors in the match column of interst, copy table/filetered results, then paste as wherever you want them (excpt for in the same rows you've just filtered to make the copy, unless you really want to have results splayed across number rows...

---